# Create a chart, with selected data from one sheet, on a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, copy-paste

I am trying to create a chart, with selected data from one sheet, on a new sheet.

```vb
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection

' add a chart and select it - Selection becomes this chart
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

'paste selection into cell C4 of Sheet2
rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4")

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
   
With ActiveChart
    'Chart type is Clustered Bar chart
    .ChartType = xlBarClustered
  
    'Set a chart title, located at the top of the chart
    .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart
  
    'Assign the content of cell B1 to the title of the chart
    .chartTitle.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
  
    'Move the chart to a new sheet 
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Sheet2"
End With
```

It shows a run-time error 13 with the `Set rng = Selection` and then sometimes an out of range error pops up around the `copy.destination`.

My thinking is that because there is not yet a sheet named "Sheet2", that is why the out of range error pops up.
When I make a sheet named Sheet2, a method `SetElement` of Chart object failed error pops up.

I tried the `Copy destinatinon` lines being within the with `ActiveChart` and outside it, and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `Set rng = Selection` will fail if something other than a range (such as a chart for example) is selected.   You can check for that using `If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then`

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Tim Williams, this could work for you:

```
Sub so75496418AddChart()

Dim rng As Range
Dim strTypeName As String, strNewSheetName As String

  strTypeName = TypeName(Selection)
  
  If strTypeName = "Range" Then

    Set rng = Selection
    
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "No data in range."
      Set rng = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'paste selection into cell C4 of Sheet2
    'rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4")
    
    strNewSheetName = "Sheet" & (Sheets.Count + 1)
    
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        'Chart type is Clustered Bar chart
        .ChartType = xlBarClustered
        
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng
      
        'Set a chart title, located at the top of the chart
        .SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart
      
        'Assign the content of cell B1 to the title of the chart
        .ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
      
        'Move the chart to a new sheet
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=strNewSheetName

    End With
    
    ' move the sheet as the last sheet:
    Sheets(strNewSheetName).Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    Set rng = Nothing
  
  Else
    MsgBox "Current selection is not a range, but a " & strTypeName & "."
  End If
  
End Sub
```

I added `.SetSourceData Source:=rng` for data source, as a chart without any data,  .`SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart` will fail.

Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setsourcedata